# getAttributes() and other related methods return only null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am experimenting with a very simple code that would replicate the **Paint Format** button. (I want to copy the formatting from the First paragraph).

However when I call the method getAttributes() in the paragraph, only Underline, Bold, Italic and Heading values are gotten. For every other property, such as FOREGROUND_COLOR return *null*

My code so far is:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var par = body.getParagraphs();
Logger.log(par[0].getAttributes());
```

from the documentation the returned value would be *null* if the paragraph has multiple values for the same Attribute property but that is not the case.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reference link to the attribute property you're looking at? There are several, and from my testing the value appears to be *null* if it doesn't stray from the default. For example, in your sample code, I get 'Null' for FOREGROUND_COLOR only when I don't change the value from the default black, for all other colours I get a value.

Comment: I can confirm the issue too. I believe it is a bug - all paragraph attributes should return their actual values, whether set explicitly or inherited from the applied heading style. There is also currently no way to infer the default heading style attributes programmatically. I have submitted a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4521) - comment/star it if you agree.

Comment: @azawaza I considered this might be a bug also, but wasn't sure. Thanks for submitting the report, have starred.

Comment: thank you @azawaza ! I didn't notice that the values returned correctly were the ones that differ from default. Have starred the issue.

Comment: The issue I have opened has been now merged into existing [Issue #4286](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4286) - make sure you star this issue to upvote it and to be notified of a fix/work-around when available.