# Google App Script: Getting NULL values from getAttributes

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, google-docs

I want to get all the attributes like(**BOLD,UNDERLINE,FOREGROUND_COLOR,FONT_SIZE** etc) from google doc. But I am getting NULL values while using getAttributes.
Following is my code.

```
var fields = doc.getNamedRanges("myFields");
var lastFontColor; 
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
  var rangeElement = fields[i].getRange().getRangeElements()[0];      
  var obj= rangeElement.getElement().asText().editAsText();
  var element= rangeElement.getElement().asText();  
  var atts = obj.getAttributes(); 
  for (var att in atts) 
  {
    Logger.log("value of " + att + ":" + atts[att]);
  }
}
```

the ouput I am getting:-

> FONT_SIZE: `null`
>   ITALIC: `null`
>   STRIKETHROUGH: `null`
>   FOREGROUND_COLOR: `#0000ff` \ fore colors comes for some of elements.
>   BOLD: `null`

Please let me know if there is any other method to do this.

Comment: I believe retrieving it `asText` strips it of formatting information. Try calling `getAttributes` on the `RangeElement` directly

Comment: Still getting the same result. I have already tried it.

Comment: when asking a question, please include relevant research and attempts you have made to try to solve the problem, to avoid wasting time.

Comment: Will mark yours words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this has been a recurring issue in Google Docs. Some of the style attributes return 'null' unless set explicitly in code.

For example, after executing the following document-bound script, I get 'null' values for FONT_SIZE, FONT_FAMILY, and some other attributes while PAGE_MARGIN and PAGE_WIDTH display correct values:

```
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var body = doc.getBody();     
 var styles = body.getAttributes();      
 Logger.log(styles);
```

However, if you explicitly set these attributes in your script, logging the output of body.getAttributes() will return these new values

```
  var styles = {};
  styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = "Times New Roman";
  styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
  body.setAttributes(styles);
```

Comment: So it means, every time if want to get the attributes of documents, I need to set these attributes first. My scenario is I have already predefined text in the doc and I want to get these text attributes. I cann't set attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. It's up to Google to fix this and they haven't budged an inch from 2014 at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835042/getattributes-and-other-related-methods-return-only-null It probably has something to do with heavy workload associated with parsing the user-created document.

Comment: Can we clarify something? Does it return null only for "default" values? I.e. if you explicitly set bold (in UI), then query it for formatting, does that bold show up? My thought is that `null` attributes simply follow document defaults. This allows updates and changes to the default template to be instantly reflected in existing documents without overwriting possibly intentional format selections that happen to align with the default in some situations.

Comment: The defaults in my case are FONT_FAMILY:"Arial" and FONT_SIZE:11, both displayed as 'null' for the newly-created template. However, the manual changes you make to the template are reflected in the attributes object.

Comment: @AntonDementiev so if you press Ctrl A in UI, then change font to something else, then run a script to query the attributes, what shows up for font: `null`, or the value set in UI?